# Unable to load Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

We're developing a dotnet core 3.0 application. We're using EF Core and the Cosmos integration for our database communication.

Running the application locally works as expected, but once we build in Azure DevOps and download the artifact to run it, the application complains that its unable to load `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. This dll is present in the dropfolder.

What am I missing here? Does EF Core require another version of this dll?

**EDIT:**

For some reason the dll has the version `2.2.0-rtm-181110` in the drop folder. And when building locally, the version is `3.1.0-preview1.19506`